# Escape character removed when using selenium execute_script through python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I need to have these characters in my string: `"'\;`

```
userID = "__\"__\'__\;__"
```

I am running javascript through python to update the username field:

```
driver.execute_script("window.document.getElementById('username').value = '%s';" %userID)
```

Now my problem is that in the end my script becomes:

```
window.document.getElementById('username').value = '__"__'__\;__';
```

And this causes errors since I have single quote without escape character. How can I keep the escape character in front of the single quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use interpolation. Instead, pass the value as a parameter to `execute_script`:

```
driver.execute_script("window.document.getElementById('username').value = arguments[0];", 
                       userID)
```

The arguments you pass to `execute_script` after the script are available as `arguments[0]`, `arguments[1]`, etc. on the JavaScript side. (This is not a special Selenium thing but how JavaScript works. The script you give to `execute_script` is wrapped in a function object and function parameters are available on the [`arguments` object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments))

When you pass the value as a parameter like above, Selenium will serialize the Python value to its corresponding JavaScript value on the browser side and it will preserve your string.