# How to pass arguments in selenimum webdriver URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to pass node_name as an argument for the below command. My code is:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://test.test.com/comp/node_name:abc');")
```

I am using selenium+Python+chromedriver here. I tried with the below command but no luck

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://test.test.com/comp/node_name:sys.argv[1]');")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape character removed when using selenium execute\_script through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745056/escape-character-removed-when-using-selenium-execute-script-through-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `execute_script()` is the string containing the script that you want to execute. Every next argument is passed on the script as an argument, and can be accessed within the script by using the `arguments[]` variable which refers to an array of arguments.

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://test.test.com/comp/node_name:' + arguments[0]);", node_name)
```

Comment: i am running the script like this python test.py abc but its not working

Comment: "python test.py abc" is passing "abc" to the script test.py, so test.py must be capturing that arg and assigning it's value to node_name which is then used in the line above.

Comment: Hi that's how it should work. But for me it's coming as node_name instead of abc

Comment: @gosatriani Based on the code samples you have given so far, it seems like you are misunderstanding something. sys.argv[1] lets you access the first command line argument in Python. You would then have to assign it to node_name, and use it as used in the code example I gave to you, OR, replace node_name in the example with sys.argv[1] directly. The JS script you pass then builds the link's string by appending this value to the string "https://test.test.com/comp/node_name:",  and passes it to the function window.open. I hope this clarifies things.