# Python: javascript error: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

When running the python script below I'm getting an error message "javascript error: missing ) after argument list".  The script is failing at "driver.execute_script(tab)".  I've tried adjusting it but I'm not able to solve it.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://techstepacademy.com/training-ground')

list = ['http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com','http://techstepacademy.com/training-ground']

for url in list:
    tab = "window.open(" + url + ",'_blank')"
    driver.execute_script(tab)
```

Comment: can you try: tab = "window.open({}, '_blank')".format(url)

Comment: Your code is dropping the URL into the JavaScript without any quotation marks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape character removed when using selenium execute\_script through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745056/escape-character-removed-when-using-selenium-execute-script-through-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add quotes around url.

```
 tab = "window.open(" + '"' + url + '"' + ",'_blank')"
```

Comment: This is very bad, because some JavaScript special character in string might appear in `url`, such as `\` or `"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid those quotes completely:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0])", url)
```