# Python Selenium: javascript error: missing ) after argument list

Tags: python, selenium

I want to use html code instead of real request.

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json

with open("user1.html") as html_file:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    html_content = html_file.read()
    driver.execute_script('document.write("{}")'.format(json.dumps(html_content)))
    # also I tried to change "" with ''
    # driver.execute_script("document.write('{}')".format(json.dumps(html_content)))
```

View **user1.html** [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16eQ-IXEAoVxd5ILP7ogsWlSgKVXakcEQ/view?usp=sharing)

I received error

> javascript error: missing ) after argument list

I tried this, but it didn't help me
[Python: javascript error: missing ) after argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221808/python-javascript-error-missing-after-argument-list)

**UPDATE**
Also I tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json

with open("user1.html") as html_file:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    html_content = html_file.read()
    driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
    print(driver.page_source)
```

But this code prints `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: Questions must be self contained. -- although it looks like that the answer is simply you have to escape JavaScript string, or find some way to pass it to JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape character removed when using selenium execute\_script through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745056/escape-character-removed-when-using-selenium-execute-script-through-python)

Comment: ... it looks like that you already find the solution; so make sure that you understand the solution completely (what it does) before applying to your code. What is your modified code?